# why I am not able to call function while defining in prototype?

Tags: javascript, jquery, inheritance

I am making an example of inheritance. I want to access all properties of `abc` and `pqr` so I used `Object.create`. However I am not able to get the value of  `r` while calling the `getr()` function. What am I doing wrong?

```js
function abc() {
  this.a = 3;
}
abc.prototype.getA = function() {
  return this.a
}

function pqr() {
  abc.call(this);
  this.r = 3;
}
pqr.prototype.getr = function() {
  return this.r
}
pqr.prototype = Object.create(abc.prototype);

var n = new pqr();
console.log(n.getr());
```

Comment: You attach `getr()` to the prototype of `pqr` and then _overwrite_ that prototype, hence why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because you overwrite the `pqr.prototype` *after* you create `getr()`. Swap the order of those statements:

```js
function abc() {
  this.a = 3;
}
abc.prototype.getA = function() {
  return this.a;
}

function pqr() {
  abc.call(this);
  this.r = 3;
}
pqr.prototype = Object.create(abc.prototype);
pqr.prototype.getr = function() {
  return this.r;
}

var n = new pqr();
console.log(n.getr());
```